# Корректно получить строку URL из аргументов функции

Tags: python

Существует некая функция create_url, в которой есть два параметра по умолчанию - *host = 'localhost'* и *port = 443*, где localhost - **string**, а 443 - **int**. Результатом работы функции должна быть строка вида *https://{host}:{port}*. Решение ниже, не проходит внутренние тесты обучающей платформы, хотя выходная строка получается с виду правильной. Возникают сомнения о типах данных, которые указаны в условии. Разъясните, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?

```
def create_url(host='localhost, port=443):
   print('https://', host, ':', port)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кавычку забыли закрыть

```
def create_url(host='localhost', port=443):
   print('https://' + host + ':' + str(port))
```

Если вы хотите в коде использовать полученную строку, то используйте этот код:

```
def create_url(host='localhost', port=443):
       return f'https://{host}:{port}'
```

Comment: Это сработало, спасибо! Теперь знаю про существование f-строк)

Comment: @NicolasSharp можно и в `print` f-строку засунуть, но я не стал.

Comment: уже попробовал, немного не пойму в чем разница,  что в первом случае строка, что во втором, выходит что в f-строку можно передавать данные любого типа, хотя и print нам этого не запрещает делать, но по результату работа с f-строкой более корректна что ли.

Comment: это более компактно

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!